# react npm start / yarn start not updating. I have to start and stop

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-lock.json

I have recently stumbled upon this exploring this boilerplate. I believe it's a bit abandoned now, but figured i'd explore it.

https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate

Currently if i update the global-css file it appears to update automatically upon save, but any other file will not. Maybe this is due to the scaffolding or structure in what's being watched.

Would love some guidance. (newbish)

Comment: This could be an issue with getting errors from your css files. I have noticed that anytime i save a broken css file and react hot reloads and displays a css error. It won't hot reload after that until I restart it. Using CRA

Comment: It's weird that I get all changes when just saving the CSS file. its like it doesn't watch the other files. @J.Cutshall